# Android SweepGradient

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw, gradient

I have a SweepGradient defined as

```
circle_paint.setShader(new SweepGradient(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, new int[] { circle_start_color, circle_end_color}, new float[] { 0f, 1f}))
```

applied to a arch defined as

```
canvas.drawArc(circle_bounds, circle_start_perc*360f, circle_end_perc*360f, true, circle_paint);
```

This workes well, but I need the arch to start drawing from the top of the screen, i.e.

```
canvas.drawArc(circle_bounds, ((circle_start_perc*360f)-90f)%360, circle_end_perc*360f, true, circle_paint);
```

The problem is that the SweepGradient seems to still start at 0 degrees, and i need it to start at 270 degrees (similar to the translation done on the drawing of the arc). In other words if I have a gradient from white to blue, I need the top of the arc painted white en the last part of the arc painted blue. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might try using `getLocalMatrix()` and `setLocalMatrix()` on the `SweepGradient` to apply a rotation to the shader.  You can get the current Matrix, post the appropriate rotation with `postRotate()` and then set it back to the shader element.

Another option would be to rotate the `Canvas` instead.  You could pre-rotate the Canvas, draw the content, and then restore it; or draw the content first and then rotate the canvas after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. I just rotated the canvas before I drew the arch and restored the canvas afterwards, worked like a charm :)

Comment: The shader rotation was an excellent suggestion. Relieves you of having to do what @BOENDAGGER did with the `save`/`restore`. Just set the shader rotation once and you are done.

Answer (score 23):

Rotating the origin of the SweepGradient using a `Matrix.preRotate`:

```
final int[] colors = {circle_start_color, circle_end_color};
final float[] positions = {0f, 1f};
Gradient gradient = new SweepGradient(circle_bounds.centerX(), circle_bounds.centerY(), colors, positions);
float rotate = 270f;
Matrix gradientMatrix = new Matrix();        
gradientMatrix.preRotate(rotate, circle_bounds.centerX(), circle_bounds.centerY());
gradient.setLocalMatrix(gradientMatrix);
mPaint.setShader(gradient);
```